# Which packages are required to put in requirements.txt when publishing a python azure function by remote build?

Tags: python, azure, deployment, package, azure-functions

This explains that you dont need some azure packages:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?pivots=python-mode-configuration&tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level#azure-functions-python-worker-dependencies

My local requirements.txt is empty.

If i do pip list i have/use the following packages locally:

```
Package              Version
-------------------- ---------
applicationinsights  0.11.10  
azure-common         1.1.28   
azure-core           1.26.4   
azure-functions      1.13.3   
azure-storage-blob   12.16.0  
azure-storage-common 2.1.0    
azure-storage-queue  12.6.0   
certifi              2022.12.7
cffi                 1.15.1   
cftime               1.6.2    
charset-normalizer   3.1.0    
colorama             0.4.6    
cryptography         40.0.2   
exceptiongroup       1.1.1    
idna                 3.4      
iniconfig            2.0.0    
install              1.3.5    
isodate              0.6.1    
netCDF4              1.6.3    
numpy                1.24.3   
packaging            23.1     
pandas               2.0.0    
pip                  23.1     
pluggy               1.0.0    
pyarrow              11.0.0   
pycparser            2.21     
pytest               7.3.1    
python-dateutil      2.8.2    
pytz                 2023.3   
requests             2.28.2   
setuptools           49.2.1
six                  1.16.0
tomli                2.0.1
typing_extensions    4.5.0
tzdata               2023.3
urllib3              1.26.15
xarray               2023.4.2
```

Most of the packages have import statements in the **inint**.py file, isn't that sufficient?

OR:
How do i determine which packages i need in the requirements.txt for this project when i publish this to azure with remote build?

Comment: Even if you add import statement in your python function init.py like this https://i.imgur.com/WUVlIEl.png you need to add those import packages in your requirements.txt like this https://i.imgur.com/jnevg6a.png if you do not add those packages in requirements.txt you will receive module not found error also while deploying the function to azure requirements.txt plays an important role as it pip installs the packages for you during deployment

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I did a remote build following the instructions here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#remote-build and it did not give any errors while deploying/building.

Comment: glad it worked but remote build also checks requirements.txt file as per this sentence - Dependencies are obtained remotely based on the contents of the requirements.txt file. Remote build is the recommended build method. in the document you shared

Answer (score 0):

I have the following import statements in my **init.py** file:-

```py
import  azure.functions  as  func
from  flask  import  Flask
```

I added the above packages in my requirements.txt folder like below:-

**My requirements.txt**

```
azure-functions
flask
```

> I have referred the func host start and func azure functionapp publish functionappname from this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish). When I ran fn + f5 key or just f key depending upon the Machine or ran below command

```bash
func host start
```

All these packages got installed in my azure function venv like below:-

[image]

[image]

Now even if I remove the above packages from requirements.txt the function will run locally as they are added in the venv packages.

***Now, I deployed the Function app with the command below as remote build:-***

```bash
func azure functionapp publish functionappname
```

**With --build remote:-**

```
func azure functionapp publish siliconfunc234 --build remote
```

The **function deployment was successful**:-

[image]

**Packages got installed like below:-**

[image]

[image]